# Why does gstreamer tee fail with udpsrc?

Tags: gstreamer

This gstreamer pipeline, with 1 sink, works:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5600 do-timestamp=true ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

This pipeline, with 2 sinks, also works:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! tee name=t ! queue ! autovideosink t. ! queue ! autovideosink
```

But this pipeline, with 2 sinks, stalls:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5600 do-timestamp=true ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! tee name=t queue ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink t. ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

Why?

Version info:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 --version
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.16.2
GStreamer 1.16.2
https://launchpad.net/distros/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer1.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should launch it with the environment variable `GST_DEBUG` set, so you get more info. For example, `GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`! tee name=t queue !`

You are missing a `!` between the `tee` and the `queue`.

Comment: Doh, such a dumb mistake. Thanks for the quick response!